# i tried to install pyinstaller and got this

Tags: python, pip, python-3.10

```
PS D:\> PIP install pyinstaller
PIP : The term 'PIP' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ PIP install pyinstaller
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PIP:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS D:\>
```

Comment: Does this issue still happen when `pip` is lowercase? At least on Linux, it is case sensitive. I don't know about Windows, but maybe.

Comment: yes in both of type lower or upper

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip3 install pyinstaller`. It happens when I'm on my MacBook.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: What OS are you using, did you have python installed before on this machine?

Comment: windows 10 ,  yes i had python 3.10

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

Add the scripts folder to PATH

C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts

or

C:\Python39\Scripts (depending on how you have installed python locate and add python/scripts folder)

*** Couldn't Edit my previous answer so i had to create a new one.